# Android Tabhost show fragment overlay

Tags: java, android, tabbar

I am having a problem using the Tabhost, when starting the app, it shows the main fragmentactivity, but it also shows me the fragment that should only be visible when the tab is selected

Main.java  extending FragmentActivity

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),MyFragment.class, null);
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentLayout, container, false);

    }   
}
```

Main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

fragmentLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".DeviceFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Did I forgot something. Right now I can see the black background color from the Main Fragment activity, but the Textlabel from my Fragment is shown at the start.
It also doesn't show me the tabhost tabbutton, only the fragment's tabbutton.
I followed https://github.com/ClareZhang/Android-FragmentTabHost-demo I even commented out all of my code, and copied it all in. But it still doesn't show me the tabhost without the fragment lying on top of it.

What did I do wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: `also shows me the fragment that should only be visible when the tab is selected` which tab did it show you?

Comment: When starting the app, it shows me Main.java on the background, and MyFragment.java is put on top. So that would be tab1

Comment: i think you misunderstood that tab one is always selected, so the content of it must be visible, you can not change the selectivity of it unless you select another tab.

Comment: Oh I understand it, The tabhost is only there to "host it", it isn't the main view, that should be happening with the fragments, right? I feel really stupid right now... Thanks

Comment: and also I can feel stupid sometime!!